# Want to access firebase cloud firestore but runtime error exist

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access my Firebase cloud firestore, but there are errors in my code.
Don't know why this code occur some error

I have Collection name is Korean. And want to add documents in 'Korean' Collection. So I call some add function Docsnippets.addShop(,,,).

To compile separately, Wrote two Java files MainActivity.java & Docsnippets.java and Docsnippets.addShop() called at Mainactivity

I think should be run correctly, but I don't know why...

This is my first time writing java&android, So sorry for you read some poor code&english

Thank you for reading my writes.

```
//debug
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.term, PID: 18908
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Arrays
        at com.example.term.MainActivity$4.onComplete(MainActivity.java:108)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18908 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

```
//logcat(?)
2019-04-30 02:17:23.642 3841-3882/? E/WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{d179055 u0 com.example.term/com.example.term.MainActivity}
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1143)
        at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:500)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3879)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5426)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

```java
package com.example.term;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 10;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    private DocSnippets db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db = new DocSnippets(mFirestore);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);
        Button emailLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_login_button);
        SignInButton googleLogin = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        googleLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

            }
        });
        emailLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createUser(editTextEmail.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    private void createUser(String email, String password) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email 가입 성공", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google 가입 성공", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            db.addShop("Korean", "내가찜한닭", "11:30:22:00", (Arrays) Arrays.asList("안동찜닭", "콜라"),(Arrays) Arrays.asList(18000, 3000));

                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }
}

'''

'''java
package com.example.term;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreSettings;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Snippets for inclusion in documentation.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "Convert2Lambda"})
public class DocSnippets implements DocSnippetsInterface {

    private static final String TAG = "DocSnippets";
    private static final ThreadPoolExecutor EXECUTOR = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 4,
            60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    private final FirebaseFirestore db;
    DocSnippets(FirebaseFirestore db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
    @Override
    public void setup() {
        // [START get_firestore_instance]
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        // [END get_firestore_instance]

        // [START set_firestore_settings]
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
                .build();
        db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
        // [END set_firestore_settings]
    }

    @Override
    public void addShop(String Kinds, String Shop_name, String Time, Arrays Menu_name, Arrays Menu_price) {
        // [START set_document]
        System.out.println("OH NO!");
        Map<String, Object> shop = new HashMap<>();
        shop.put("name", Shop_name);
        shop.put("time", Time);
        shop.put("menu_name", Menu_name);
        shop.put("menu_price", Menu_price);
        db.collection(Kinds).document(Shop_name)
                .set(shop)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                    }
                });
        // [END set_document]
    }

    @Override
    public void getShop(String Kinds, String Shop_name) {
        // [START get_document]
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(Kinds).document(Shop_name);
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
        // [END get_document]
    }

    @Override
    public void getAllUsers() {
        // [START get_all_users]
        db.collection("users")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
        // [END get_all_users]
    }

    @Override
    public void docReference() {
        // [START doc_reference]
        DocumentReference alovelaceDocumentRef = db.collection("users").document("alovelace");
        // [END doc_reference]
    }

    @Override
    public void collectionReference() {
        // [START collection_reference]
        CollectionReference usersCollectionRef = db.collection("users");
        // [END collection_reference]
    }

    @Override
    public void getAllDocs() {
        // [START get_multiple_all]
        db.collection("cities")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
        // [END get_multiple_all]
    }
}
'''

'''
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.term, PID: 902
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzkj.run(Unknown Source:21)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/util/Function;
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzfu.zzd(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzeg.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzcj.zza(Unknown Source:74)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzcl.run(Unknown Source:8)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzkg$zza.run(Unknown Source:16)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.util.Function" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzfu.zzd(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzeg.<init>(Unknown Source:5) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzcj.zza(Unknown Source:74) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzcl.run(Unknown Source:8) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:459) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-firestore.zzkg$zza.run(Unknown Source:16) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.example.term-kj_zrYeYg7nGbyiDIJMp4w==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:764)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:847)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1088)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6095)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1785)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
'''
```

Comment: What are the exact error message and stack trace that you get when you run this code? Please find them in your logcat output, and add them to your question by clicking the edit link under it.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Thank you! Is this right logcat?

Comment: I don't know java good enough to be able to resolve it but according to the tracelog `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Arrays` the error is in line 108. Something related to java arrays...

Comment: @Christian K yep, but I fixed that, then below error occur..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says:

> ClassCastException: `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` cannot be cast to `java.util.Arrays`

Which relates to two statements you have of this format:

```
(Arrays) Arrays.asList("안동찜닭", "콜라")
```

If you look at the error message, and to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)), you will see that `Arrays.asList` returns a `List` and not an `Arrays`.

If you really want, you can cast the result to an `ArrayList`:

```
(ArrayList) Arrays.asList("안동찜닭", "콜라")
```

But I'd highly recommend against that, and just remove the cast. Using the `List` as just that is less likely to break in the future:

```
Arrays.asList("안동찜닭", "콜라")
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I have another problem, So I edited body, can you see about that?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/58973e33dfdd39a9ded36e7e6887c8feef7493b1/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/DocSnippets.java
In here, at line 349, I understand it suggest me using arrays like Arrays.asList(1,2,3).

Comment: Thank you. I solve this problem. I changed form of arrays and other problems are firebase's own problem. So I update version of firebase, and other problems are solved.